# How to change order of the modules in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and I am facing the following issue.

I have two modules (Module A, Module B). Module B updates a record in database for module A to retrieve the record and process it. However, I am facing an issue where Module A is running first and than Module B.This means that Module A is unable to get the latest record updated by Module B. How can I change the sequence where Module B runs first so that it updates a record and Module A is able to get the latest updated record.

I have tried to put the following code in Module A config file but it is not working.

```
<depends>
   <B_Module />
</depends>
```

How can I do adjust the sequence of module running the codes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jervine can you explain further?

Comment: can you please share code.

Comment: Hi @DhirenVasoya, i am unable to do it.